# How to split a string using split(<regexp>) and get the separators?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

I would like to split the following string at each letter using **String.prototype.split(/[a-zA-Z]/)**:

```
'M 10 10L 150 300'
```

The result:

```
[ "", " 10 10", " 150 300" ]
```

But I want to receive this:

```
[ "", "M 10 10", "L 150 300" ]
```

---

What is the fastest way to get that result using JavaScript?

Comment: This comes close: `input.split(/(?=[A-Za-z])/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use match with `/[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*/g` to capture a letter and the following non letter characters:

```js
let s = 'M 10 10L 150 300'

console.log(
  s.match(/^[^a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*/g)   // ^[^a-zA-Z]+ to include the case when 
                                               // the string doesn't begin with a letter
)
```

Comment: This is missing the first empty string entry.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah. Not sure how critical it is.

Comment: @Psidom, Not critical!!! :)